# REST call not working with Camel running in Docker

Tags: docker, rest, apache-camel

I have this Camel Rest Route:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import spark.Spark;

public class MainCamel {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Main camelMain = new Main();
    camelMain.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            this.getContext().getRegistry().bind("healthcheck", CheckUtil.class);
            this.restConfiguration()
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                    .component("netty-http")
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port(11010);
            this.rest("/healthcheck")
                    .get()
                    .description("Healthcheck for docker")
                    .outType(Integer.class)
                    .to("bean:healthcheck?method=healthCheck");
        }
    });

    // spark
    Spark.port(11011);
    Spark.get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");

    System.out.println("ready");
    camelMain.run(args);
}

public static class CheckUtil {
    public Integer healthCheck() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

I also created a second REST server with Spark.
The Camel route does NOT work if the code is executed in a Docker container.
`Exception: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:11010 failed to respond`
The Spark server works fine.

However when executing the code directly in IntelliJ both REST Servers work. Of course both ports are exposed in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the Netty HTTP server to `localhost`. Meaning that it will not be able to serve requests that originate from outside of the container.

Change `.host("localhost")` to `.host("0.0.0.0")` so that the sever listens on all available network interfaces.